# JavaScript ES6 import syntax?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, import, es6-modules

I am just testing the new `import` syntax. But I get a bit frustrated since the syntax I have to use does not seem to be what I have been reading. Why is the syntax below working (in Chrome, in an extension)?

```
import * as lib from "./lib-file.js";
```

What alternatives are there for this special syntax?

---

EDIT: I think I must clarify some things. I am trying to get this to work in a Chrome extension. The syntax above works in the "popup" script (in a script loaded from the html file there). I wrote this post because I was surprised that I needed the ".js" extension.

However then a new problem showed up. The above syntax does not work in a "content" script. The error I get is the same as the one I get from the popup when there is no `type="module"` in the script tag in the html file. (`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token *`) This looks like a bug when importing to a content script, but I am not at all sure. Am I missing something there?

---

EDIT 2: I just found this article which seems to tell how to fix these problems for now:

Using JavaScript ES6 import/export modules in Chrome Extensions https://medium.com/@martinnovk_22870/using-javascript-es6-import-export-modules-in-chrome-extensions-f63a3a0d2736

---

EDIT 3:
I just got a pointer to this utility. I notice that they do not use ES6 import in their suggested setup in the browser. 
mozilla/webextension-polyfill: A lightweight polyfill library for Promise-based WebExtension APIs in Chrome https://github.com/mozilla/webextension-polyfill

Comment: That just means to import all exported modules with prefix of lib from the given file. 
There are multiple variations of import and the use case depends on the module you are importing.

Comment: @dvlden Thanks, but I am asking about the syntax, not the semantics.

Answer (score 0):

You can use different `import` calls - maybe even `require` if your server is Node:

```
const lib = require("./lib-file");
import "./lib-file";
import libFile from "lib-file";
```

Note that in the third one, you need to `export libFile` from your `lib-file.js`.

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of these variants, but they are not the same as the one I am asking about. (This is not in Node.js.)

Comment: Then which ones are you asking about @Leo?

Comment: I think I saw for example this variant `import * as lib from "lib-file"`. And a variant with "./lib-file".

Comment: I just tested your second and third variant. I can't get them to work. (I am using "use strict".)

Comment: Hm, my bad. Maybe they work. I missed that the error now was from the "content.js" (the file running in the current tab context). Import there does not work with the syntax I use (and probably not with the other syntaxes either. From "content.js" I get the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token *`. From my experience right now I understand this as that the file to import was not found.

Comment: That "lib-file.js" is not found from the import in the content file in the extension seems to be a bug. (I have no idea how to work around it. Except of course by copying the code I wanted to import...)